# Issue with more multiple functions in one onClick

Tags: javascript

I have two function and I need to execut in one `onClick`. The first one is to confirm the submit, if the user press `yes` it should execute the second function. It is not working with me. Any help please.

below my code:

```
<Script>

function checkSubmit(){

if(confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the data?');)
    sendData();
}

</Script>
```

The button:

```
<input type="submit" id="send_data"  class="send_data" value="Send" onclick="checkSubmit()"/>
```

THANKS FOR ALL ^_^

Comment: Semicolon is the problem  . Remove it and try if(confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the data?'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it almost right.  I think your semi-colon is messing you up in your if statement.

***[Check out this jsFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/qRyp4/)***

```
function checkSubmit() { 
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the data?')) 
        sendData(); 
}

function sendData() { alert("data sent"); }
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. if I want to stop submitting the form when the user click no, How ?

Comment: I believe you would just do `else return false;`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the standard event binding mechanism:

```
elem.addEventListener('click', yourFunc, false); // for good browsers

elem.attachEvent('onclick', yourFunc);  // for old IE versions
```

and you can add as many listeners as you need

here's a reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent

Answer (score 1):

It's simply that  you have a semi-colon in your if statement.
You need something like that :

```
function checkSubmit() {
    var b = confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the data?');
    if ( b ) {
        sendData();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Edited: If you want to stop the submit of the form you can do this:

```
<form name="example" action="your url here" method="get" onsubmit="return checkSubmit();">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" id="send_data" class="send_data" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Script>  

function checkSubmit(){

if(confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the data?'))  //you have small error here
    sendData();

 }
</Script>
```